# Output file was not created error when merging TIFF files using GDAL

Tags: gdal

Merge TIFF files using GDAL. Output file was not created. How can I solve it?

Code

```
import subprocess
import glob
import os
import shlex

file_list = glob.glob(r"E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\*.tif")
files_string = " ".join(file_list)
output_path = r"E:\Spekter\Task 2\output.tif"
command = f"gdal_merge.py -o {output_path} -of gtiff {files_string}"

print("Command:", command)
os.system(command)

if os.path.exists(output_path):
  print(f"Output file '{output_path}' created successfully.")
else:
  print("Output file was not created. Check for errors and permissions.")
```

Output

```
Command: gdal_merge.py -o E:\Spekter\Task 2\output.tif -of gtiff E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\618_5405.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\618_5406.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\618_5407.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\619_5403.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\619_5404.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\619_5405.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\619_5406.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\619_5407.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\619_5408.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\619_5409.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\620_5400.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\620_5401.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\620_5402.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\620_5403.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\620_5404.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\620_5405.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\620_5406.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\620_5407.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\620_5408.tif E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\620_5409.tif
Output file was not created. Check for errors and permissions.
```

Comment: There is a space in output file path. Try to quote the output argument: `command = f'gdal_merge.py -o "{output_path}" -of gtiff {files_string}'`

Comment: I would first try with a path that has no space in the name `Task 2` ->  `Task2`.

Comment: The following code not worked.

import subprocess
import glob
import os
import shlex

file_list = glob.glob(r"E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\*.tif")
files_string = " ".join(file_list)
output_path = r"E:\Spekter\Task2\output.tif"
command = command = f'gdal_merge.py -o "{output_path}" -of gtiff {files_string}'

print("Command:", command)
os.system(command)

if os.path.exists(output_path):
  print(f"Output file '{output_path}' created successfully.")
else:
  print("Output file was not created. Check for errors and permissions."

Comment: Have you tried to run the command directly in a shell? May be you get some output that can help you. You can also add `-v` to get more output.

Comment: I have run the basic command in a shell. But I have to write in python. I am a beginner in GDAL. Can you help me write the full code.  My task it that
Merge TIFF files using GDAL.
Scenario: Create a tool that takes a folder path as input, and merges all the .tif files within a folder into a single TIFF file using GDAL.
Input
Folder Location
Output
Merged TIFF file

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code slightly

```
import subprocess
import glob
import os
import shlex

file_list = glob.glob(r"C:\data\dem\P*.tif")
files_string = " ".join(file_list)
output_path = r"C:\data\dem\output.tif"
command = f"gdal_merge.py -o {output_path} -of gtiff {files_string}"

print("Command:", command)
os.system(command)

if os.path.exists(output_path):
  print(f"Output file '{output_path}' created successfully.")
else:
  print("Output file was not created. Check for errors and permissions.")
```

Then I executed it successfully:

```
python mergetest.py
Command: gdal_merge.py -o C:\data\dem\output.tif -of gtiff C:\data\dem\Ptest.tif
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
Output file 'C:\data\dem\output.tif' created successfully.
```

It worked also with a longer `{files_string}`. Your code works, check again the input and output strings.

Comment: Not Wokred. I don't know where is the problem. Please suggest how I can I solve.

import subprocess
import glob
import os
import shlex

file_list = glob.glob(r"E:\Spekter\data\data\Task2\*.tif")
files_string = " ".join(file_list)
output_path = r"E:\Spekter\Task2\output.tif"
command = f"gdal_merge.py -o {output_path} -of gtiff {files_string}"

print("Command:", command)
os.system(command)

if os.path.exists(output_path):
  print(f"Output file '{output_path}' created successfully.")
else:
  print("Output file was not created. Check for errors and permissions.")

Comment: I can only suggest to make a test with a single tiff file as an input first. Maybe some of the tiff files in the list is corrupted or maybe the command line has too many characters or something. Generally speaking gdalbuildvrt https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html is better than gdal_merge for most use cases.